# Immutable NSJSONReadingOptions in NSJSONSerialization

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsjsonserialization

To DeSerialize a JSON String I am using the following method:

```
+ (id)JSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)data options:(NSJSONReadingOptions)opt error:(NSError **)error
```

But, I found that reading option returns mutable Object. Is there a way using which I will be able receive object which is immutable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should only get mutable objects if your `NSJSONReadingOptions` parameter includes `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers`. Indeed, when I call with `options` of `0`, I get a standard `NSDictionary`, but if I use `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers`, I get a `NSMutableDictionary`. What are you using for your `options` value?

Comment: I was looking for options value, which you have mentioned. 0 works. Is it documented somewhere.          Thanks.

Comment: See [`NSJSONReadingOptions`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSJSONReadingOptions).

Comment: but it does not mention for value as "0"

Comment: Agreed. One is left to infer that if you don't choose the `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` (which enables mutable containers), that the containers are therefore immutable. And because this is a bitwise operator, 0 means that none of the options are selected.

Comment: @Rob I'm a bit confused here, why use option that is not on the list of possible values, if there is no documentation what it does I think we should't rely on it as it may change on new releases of iOS

Comment: @JulianKról - Are you talking about the fact that `0`/`kNilOptions` is not listed? When dealing with bitwise operators, the zero option is never included in the Apple documentation, but is always implicit. (The same is true with the `[]` option value in Swift 2.)

Comment: @Rob, yes this is what I was referring to. Okay, I'm not trying to guess why they support 0 but I'm worried about its implications as it is undocumented value thus I wouldn't use it

Answer (score 4):

For better readability you can use `kNilOptions` instead of `0`.

From http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

> ... `kNilOptions` is just a constant for 0 – I find its name very
>   descriptive though, so I always prefer it over just the value of 0 as
>   a method parameter.